# Awesonium Linux C# System.DllNotFoundException: Could not locate the path to the native Awesomium library

Tags: ubuntu, mono, c#

```
I am  running Ubuntu 16.04 and the Awesomium Web Browser C# Framework as well as Mono 4.4.2 with the environment variable MONO_PATH set to /usr/lib/mono/4.5 and the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to /home/frankc/EnvironmentX64/Hybrid/Debug.
```

In the directory folder /home/frankc/EnvironmentX64/Hybrid/Debug, I have copies of the dll assembly awesomium , libffmpegsumo.so , libawesomium-1-7.so.0.0 , awesomium_process , Awesomium.Mono.dll , Awesomium.Core.dll
and Awesomium.Mono.dll.

When I compile the following C# test program , it compiles okay with no errors.

```
// Credit: Awesomium v1.7.2 C# Basic Sample
//         by Perikles C. Stephanidis
using System;
using System.IO;
using Awesomium.Core;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BasicSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            WebCore.Initialize(WebConfig.Default);

            Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine("WE ARE HERE " + WebCore.PackagePath); 

            using ( WebSession session = WebCore.CreateWebSession(WebPreferences.Default) )
            {
                // WebView implements IDisposable. Here we demonstrate
                // wrapping it in a using statement.
                using ( WebView view = WebCore.CreateWebView( 1100, 600, session ) )
                {
                    bool finishedLoading = false;
                    bool finishedResizing = false;

                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Loading: {0} ...", url ) );

                    // Load a URL.
                    view.Source = url;

                    // This event is fired when a frame in the
                    // page finished loading.
                    view.LoadingFrameComplete += ( s, e ) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Frame Loaded: {0}", e.FrameId ) );

                        // The main frame usually finishes loading last for a given page load.
                        if ( e.IsMainFrame )
                            finishedLoading = true;
                    };

                    while ( !finishedLoading )
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep( 100 );
                        // A Console application does not have a synchronization
                        // context, thus auto-update won't be enabled on WebCore.
                        // We need to manually call Update here.
                        WebCore.Update();
                    }

                    // Print some more information.
                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Page Title: {0}", view.Title ) );
                    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "Loaded URL: {0}", view.Source ) );
                } // Destroy and dispose the view.
           } // Release and dispose the session.            

           // Shut down Awesomium before exiting.
            WebCore.Shutdown();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler command :

mcs -r:./Awesomium.Mono.dll Test.cs

Yet when I run mono ./Test.exe , I observe the following run-time exception:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Could not locate the path to the native Awesomium library.
  at Awesomium.Core.WebCore.YFqkBlruD () <0x40641080 + 0x00853> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Awesomium.Core.WebCore.EHyMTEo9AN () <0x4063cc30 + 0x00913> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Awesomium.Core.WebCore.CreateWebView (Int32 width, Int32 height) <0x4063c9a0 + 0x00073> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at BasicSample.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x40620d70 + 0x000bb> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Also, when I run mono ./Test.exe, I notice that the string WebCore.PackagePath is empty which is not what I expected since WebCore.PackagePath should point at the location for the dll assembly awesomium. Furthermore WebCore.PackagePath is a get property rather than a get and set property so I cannot change its value. Is there another similar property
I could set to fix the System.DllNotFoundException: Could not locate the path to the native Awesomium library?

I have downloaded the GITHUB Awesomium WebBrowser  C# source code and was unable to grep the string "Could not locate the path to the native Awesomium library".

strace mono ./Test.exe and export MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono ./Test.exe revealed nothing immediately noticeable.

Could I find out the reason for the MonoSystem.DLLNotFoundException and how to fix it?

Today, I was able to compile, link and run the two Awesomium web browser C++ test programs and verify that they executed correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you `export MONO_PATH` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: @Stephen Harris, Thank you for your great comment. Yes, I exported MONO_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I searched the GITHUB mono/mono distribution archives for the string  "Could not locate the path to the native Awesomium library" and could not find an exact match.

Comment: @Stephen Harris, If my C++ :Ubuntu Linux 16.04 test programs run perfectly well , then why do not my C# Ubuntu 16.04 tests run without a problem, They both share the same MONO_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH> Thank you.

Comment: @Stephen Harris. I just answered the original question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A diff of strace outputs  beween the C# executable  and the C++ executable reveals Awesomnium has non-functional sample programs with missing entry points in the native Awesomnium library. Please avoid for a while to save headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered over the last 48 hours that the Awesomium's C# NET product has a lot of configuration problems and changing DLLImports which make it almost useless if you do not pay for support.

Our architect recommended spawning a web browser using C# which I just tested successfully.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

Process proc = new Process ();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "http://stackoverflow.com";
proc.Start ();
```